# Display Skype Meeting Broadcast in SharePoint online

Tags: office-365

How to display "Skype Meeting Broadcast" in my office 365 site? I have created meeting meeting in "Skype Meeting Broadcast", now I want to display this meeting in my office 365 site. How can I do this? Please help me in this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The broadcast has it's own dedicated page. You can find the link at broadcast.skype.com. In the meeting details, there will be a join link. Distribute this to your users. If you feel the need to display it somewhere else, then you can take that url and use a page viewer web part to embed it, but that'd be a real weird experience.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes this way I can display it in my page, but this way I can display any particular meeting and it will be custom work. Is there a way to dynamically fetch all the meeting and display in Office 365 site? In short whenever someone add a meeting in "Skype broadcast Meeting" I want that it will automatically display in my office 365 site.